# Error when putting variable in table, only constants allowed?

Tags: replace, netlogo

Currently I am working on a Netlogo program where I need to use nodes and links for vehicle routing problem. (links are called streets in the program)

Here I have some practical problems of how to input variable linkspeed in a table with another node. Constants like 200 etc are fine. Online I found some examples where variables are used, but I do not know why I keep getting the following error:

> Expected a constant.

(or why netlogo expects a constant)

Here is the relevant piece of code:

```
extensions [table]
streets-own [linkspeed linktoll] 
nodes-own [netw]

;; In another piece of code linkspeed is assigned successfully to the links

to cheapcalc

  ;; start conditions set costs very high 300000

  ;; state 3 unsearched state 2 searching state 1 searched (for later purposes)

  ask nodes [ 

    set i 0 set j count nodes set netw table:make


    while [i < j][


    table:put netw (i) [3000000 3]   set i (i + 1)]]  


  set i 0 let k 0

  ask node 35      ;; here i use node 35 as an example. 

                   ;; node 35 is connected to node 34, 36, 20 and 50

     [table:put netw (35) [0 1]   ;; node need to search costs to travel to itself 

                                   ;; putting constants is ok. 

     while [i < j]

        [ask my-links 

           [ask both-ends 

              [if (who != 35) [set color blue     

;;               set temp ([linkspeed] of street 35 who)    ;; here my real goal is to put this in stat of i. but i is easier than linkspeed. 

                 table:put netw (who) [ i 2 ]

                 ]              

           ]  ]


      set i (i + 1)] ] ;; next node for later, no it is just repetition of the same. 


end
```

I hope somebody knows what is going on...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely not putting a variable in a table, but putting a variable in a list (which you're then putting in a table).

Change the line below:

```
     table:put netw (who) [ i 2 ]
```

to:

```
     table:put netw (who) (list i 2)
```

This - (list i 2) - allows you to generate a list with variables in it, you can't do it the other way - [i 2].

Hope this helps.